# How to change the plot color after a button press in matplotlib/tkinter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tkinter, interactive

I am new to Python. I want to update the displayed plot after a button press. For example I want to change the color.

Thanks for your help!

```py
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class App(Frame):
    def change_to_blue(self):
        # todo self.ax.plot.color = 'blue' ????
        # todo self.fig.update() ???
        print('graph should be blue now instead of red')

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        Button(master, text="Switch Color to blue", command=lambda: self.change_to_blue()).pack()

        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.plot(x, y, color='red')

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()


x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the color of the `Line2D` object created by `ax.plot`.
Store it in `self`, then you will be able to access it in your action handler.

```
def __init__(self, master):
    ...
    # ax.plot returns a list of lines, but here there's only one, so take the first
    self.line = self.ax.plot(x, y, color='red')[0]
```

Then, you can change said line's color in your handler. You need to call `canvas.draw` to force the line to be re-rendered.

```
def change_to_blue(self):
    self.line.set_color('blue')
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for. Is this the same way how I would change the other things besides of color? For example the data?

Comment: Yep, you can use `line.set_ydata` for instance